# convergence of an integral involving exponential function

Tags: real-analysis

Is the integral  $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}$ is covergent?

I thought of making an upper bound or lower bound . Between $0$ and $\infty$, $e^{-x}$ is $\le$ 1 hence $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2} \le \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}=tan^{-1}x$ over the limits $\infty $ and $0$ gives $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

On the other side $e^{-x}$ is bigger. I am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral does not converge. As you noted, there is trouble for large negative $x$.

If $x$ is negative, let $t=-x$. Consider $\frac{e^t}{1+t^2}$ where $t$ is positive. We have $e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\cdots$. Thus $e^t\gt \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}t^2$, and therefore $\frac{e^t}{1+t^2}\gt \frac{1}{2}$.

We have shown that in the interval $(-\infty,0)$, the integrand $\frac{e^{-x}}{1_x^2}$ is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$, so the improper integral does not converge.

One can show that in fact $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The integrand tends to $+\infty$ as $x$ tends to $-\infty$. This is easily verified using L'Hospitals rule. So can the integral be convergent?